# Prevent/customize android scrolling to focused input

Tags: javascript, android, css, android-browser

On my form I have a header which uses fixed positioning and a div of height 100% which contains the form inputs. When an input is focused android scrolls the page to that input, which places the input 'behind' the header (although android does keep the input visible by rendering it on top of the header it doesn't do this for labels and neighbouring inputs so it's difficult for the user to know which input they're on).

Is there some way I can disable or control the scrolling amount?